# Video track hierarchy isn't allowing me to use split screen, in davinci resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve

I have 4 video clips loaded into Davinci Resolve, and my goal is to get all 4 of them to show like a grid. So I put 2 of them on separate video tracks, and was editing the zoom and position of each clip when I found that only one was showing at a time.

It turns out that for some reason, only the video clip on the highest video track (say, Video 6) is showing, and the other videos on lower number video tracks (say, Video 5) isn't showing.

Here is a screenshot to hopefully demonstrate my issue further:

[image: screenshot showing the error]

The video's border is still appearing in the transform, but the video itself isn't showing.

I've done this before with other videos and have had no issues. I did multiple google searches but wasn't able to find anyone complaining of this issue. Am I missing something very simple?

If any more information is needed please let me know and I'll be glad to provide it.